# C# - Is there a reason NOT to instantiate a class and use it in a single line of code?

Tags: c#, class, dispose, using-statement

I know this would be a correct way to use a StreamWriter:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(hreq.GetRequestStream()))
    sw.Write(jsonPostData);
```

But what about this? Is this also valid or to be avoided? Would it be properly disposed?

```
new StreamWriter(hreq.GetRequestStream()).Write(jsonPostData);
```

Comment: In the first block of code, it's disposed because you're using a `using` statement. In the second code block, you'd have to explicitly call its `Dispose()` method.

Comment: No.  Dispose is _not_ called by the garbage collector.  It needs to be called by user code.

Comment: A bit picky - the *correct* way is not super correct. `StreamWriter` requires a writable stream, and throws exception when stream is readonly. If `hreq.GetRequestStream()` returns a readonly stream, the code terminates at `new StreamWriter()`, and the reaonly stream will **not** be disposed / closed.

Comment: The second one should be avoided. The first one needs brackets :)

Comment: Don't do this. however if you want to type less characters with less code clutter you can use the new using syntax in C# 8  `using var sw = new StreamWriter(hreq.GetRequestStream();` which reduces nesting and scopes itself for you

Answer (score 2):

When using `IDisposable`s (i.e., usually external resources), you need to call `Dispose()` on them. `using` is syntactic sugar that does that for you, but the principal remains - you use some special call to make sure `Dispose()` is called. In the second snippet, `Dispose()` is not called, and you'll leak a resource until the program terminates.

Comment: Not until program is terminated. But until no more references point to the object.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe The GC thread does not invoke Dispose(). But the finalizer thread invokes the finalizer.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe in many cases time when GC runs and program terminates is the same. Note that "no more references point to the object" is not related to releasing memory/resources at all.

Comment: Dear @AlexeiLevenkov can you elaborate on that? "in many cases time when GC runs and program terminates is the same"

Comment: Dispose is a word it's finally means de-allocation . i don't know why we are focusing on namings .

Comment: @Mr.AF It's not the naming we are focusing on. Please be fair. He said "you'll leak a resource until the program terminates." and you said  "Not until program is terminated. But until no more references point to the object". Your comment lacks to mention the need to implement a finalizer and de-allocating any unmanaged resources there to be true.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Gen2 GC (which is generation that actually calls finalizers) runs rarely and it needs to detect enough memory pressure to actually run. If your machine has enough resources (and especially in 64 bit process) there is often not enough pressure to actually trigger Gen 2 collection. As result it may not ever happen for particular execution of a program. One can treat program termination as imaginary Gen2 GC run (indeed better comment would be "time when GC would run finalization may be past termination of the program")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you very much for the time to explain. Enlightening. In that case, my comment is also not true. even a finalizer cannot guarantee cleanup. FYI all.

Comment: @OguzOzgul actually my comment about Gen2 is wrong - not sure why I thought so as finalizers runs after GC so they would not slow down Gen0/Gen1 either... Correct correct statement I should have made is  "GC may never need to run before app terminates" which is less likely than I estimated - Gen0 should be somewhat frequent, but there is no guarantees (more on finalization from the expert - https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. That was what I knew, and my first comment had this in mind. All finalizable objects when instantiated are added to the finalizer queue, and object finalization will eventually occur, because even a Gen0 collection will put dead finalizable objects in the freachable queue for finalization. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_Finalize

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share a safer version:

```
// In case hreq.GetRequestStream() returns a readonly stream,
// which causes new StreamWriter(Stream) to throw exception
using (var stream = hreq.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    { 
        sw.Write(jsonPostData);
    }
}
```